# "setState" is not working for image update

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a statefull class, and i just wanna update a image when clicked in a arrow icon, but setstate isn't working....

My statefull class:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
...
}
```

My varible with image path is here:

```
              Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(13, 80, 82, 0.7),
                              width: 1.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                          height: 293.0,
                          width: 130.0,
                          child: Image.asset(_avatarSelectec),
                        ),
```

My setState when icon is clicked:

```
         IconButton(
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(6, 30, 40, 0.9),
                      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                              _userAvatar++;
                              _avatarSelectec = "img/avatar/free/" +_userAvatar.toString() + ".gif";
                              print(_avatarSelectec);
                              print(_userAvatar);
                            });
                          },
                        ),
```

I'm printting the varible with the path (_avatarSelectec) and variable with the image number (_userAvatar) both are correct in the log, but nothing happens...
I dont think this is wrong... cant see my mistake....

Comment: Have you added your `assets` path to your `pubspec.yaml` file?

Comment: Yes.. otherwise i would receive error xD
i'm printting the variables... look the log when i print _userAvatar and _avatarSelectec:

I/flutter (29480): img/avatar/free/2.gif
I/flutter (29480): 2
They are right....

Comment: it doesn’t work because setState in your case rebuilds only Button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try wrapping your Image.asset widget with ValueListenableBuilder, and make _userAvatar a ValueNotifier

Comment: Thanks bro! Worked!!
Any ideia why my code doesn't work? Cause It seems right to me.

Comment: I don't know. It may be something else in your code, may be something about cache.. I personally stick to ValueListnenableBuilders wherever I can, these are really handy "embedded" stateful widgets.

Comment: I have a request that i use memoize to cache, but it's inside another function and screen... do you think it has some realtion? Thanks a lot bro, 'im still learning xD
by the way, do you have any site or course to recommend?